# How to convert this JS code to be asynchronous

Tags: javascript

Given a set of select boxes that depend on each other (selecting something in A populates B with values) I am looking to build an object with the possible value combinations.

```
# out = { FieldNameA: [ { key: 'A', value: '', dep: { FieldNameB: [ { key: 'B', value: '', dep: [] } ] } } ] }
```

This is the code I'm using.

```
function getFieldValues(selectors) {
  if (selectors.length == 0) {
    return [];
  }

  var fieldInfo = selectors.shift();
  var field = document.querySelector(fieldInfo['selector']);

  for (var i=0; i<field.options.length; i++) {
    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    evt.initEvent("change", false, true);

    field.selectedIndex = i;
    field.dispatchEvent(evt);

    var option = field.options[i]; 
    var fieldName = fieldInfo['name'];

    if (!result[fieldName]) {
      result[fieldName] = [];
    }

    var fieldData = { key: option.value, value: option.innerHTML };

    alert('starting child retrieval of data');
    var dependencies = getFieldValues(selectors.slice(0));

    if (dependencies) {
      fieldData['dependencies'] = dependencies;
    }

    result[fieldName].push(fieldData);
  }

  return result;
}

out = getFieldValues(selectors);
console.log(JSON.stringify(out));
```

I need to make it async to add a delay after the dispatch event code so the values in the second selects get populated. However my attempts at converting this code have failed.

Comment: So you want to execute `field.options.length` number of async tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simple way to handle async for each loop is by do this

```
function myfunc(callback) {
  var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
  dfd.done(callback);
  var A = [var1,var2,var3]
  var index = 0;
  var next = function() {
    if(index<A.length) {
      var item = A[index];
      index++;
      // Do what you want.
      setTimeout(next, 1); // or only next();
    } else {
      dfd.done();
    }
  };
  next();
}
```

Comment: If you look closely there is also recursion.

Comment: I can not see any problem by use you recursion, but the hard problem here is I not has point out is how to collect the result from the system. If you use JQuery you can use JQuery deferred patten.
http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/
The Jquery patten here is some bit hard to understand but very useful for this type of task.

Comment: Can not use jQuery since this code could be executed on any site via a bookmarklet.

Comment: Ok, you can do a simple JQuery deferred patten by your self.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it asynchronous and add a delay you can use a javascript **Timing Event**

```
setTimeout(function(){<Code you want to execute>}, <delay in milliseconds>);
```

Check: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Hope this helps